# Dropdown is required even informing value - Voyager Laravel

Tags: laravel, voyager

I'm using Voyager Laravel, in a selectbox relation field with another table, even selecting an option is showing an error that the field is required. What to do?

Relationship:

[Relationship image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myoC1.png)

Form:

[Form Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OIWa.png)

Answer (score 1):

Make the respective column optional in database. It will work.

Voyager automatically adds required attribute to the field when the column in database is set to 'Not Null'

Also set below rules for field in BREAD

```
{
    "validation": {
        "rule": "nullable|url"
    }
}
```

Comment: the column is set as optional in the database... this is not working

Answer (score 0):

Check de id field that you're using as a base for the relationship, maybe it has the same restriction.